# Getting error installing Provisioning Profile on mac. (Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Xamarin forms ios app with push notifications enabled. It works fine with a Distribution provisioning profile but not with the Development profile. I have uploaded the certificates for Development and Distribution in the Identifier of my app for apple account. Now when I'm downloading and installing the profile which uses the App ID(Identifier), I am getting the below error every time:

```
Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device.

Please ensure the provisioning profile is configured for this device. If not, please try to generate a new profile.
```

I am getting this error on installing every profile. 
mac version is 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4 (11E146).

I have tried the Download Manual Profiles option in Xcode preferences for my account. Please help me with fixing this blocker.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with exactly your configuration (mac version is 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4 ). Never had this before.

Answer (score 24):

In Xcode, open **Window > Devices and Simulators > Select Device > Unpair Device** (for all devices) open .mobileprovision again. Good luck!

Comment: Worked! - Tip ... the 'for all devices' was important for me

Comment: Awesome Answer feel like save my life ...!

Comment: You save my day...Thanks

Comment: I was able to unpair just the current device attached, then re-add it from the "+" button below the list. And that seemed to work, thx.

Comment: Additionally, I unplugged the device, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved that. Believe this is a bug.

Try this:

- open Devices and Simulators
- right click on your iPhone
- choose "Show Provisioning Profiles"
- click the plus icon at the bottom and add your profile

After that the profile should install.

Comment: Did you add your device to the developer portal and selected it while generating the profile?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue for Xcode 12.4. I tried following steps to fix it.

1. Make sure any connected iPhones/devices are unlocked then trying installing again.
2. Select Xcode => Preferences => Accounts => Sign in with your app specific developer account => and select Download Manual Profiles
3. Open Devices and Simulators and unpair all paired devices